# Run an aggregation using Java Driver - MongoDB

Tags: java, mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-java-driver

Using MongoDB shell I use:

```
db.bios.aggregate(
[
{$match:{"contribs.0.name":{"$exists":1}}}, 
{$project: {contribs:{$arrayElemAt:["$contribs",0]}}}
]
)
```

How can I make the same query using Java driver (**2.14.1**)?
I try with:

At first I create a DBObject for `$match` stage:

```
DBObject match = new BasicDBObject("$match",new BasicDBObject("contribs.0.name",
                 new BasicDBObject("$exists",1)));
```

Then I create a `BasicDBList`:

```
BasicDBObject obj = new BasicDBObject("$contribs",0);

BasicDBList arrayElemAt = new BasicDBList();
arrayElemAt.add(obj);
```

And this is the `$project` stage:

```
DBObject project1 = new BasicDBObject("$project", new BasicDBObject("contribs",
                    new BasicDBObject("$arrayElemAt",arrayElemAt)));
```

Finally I create the aggregation pipeline:

```
List<DBObject> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(match);
list.add(project1);

AggregationOutput output = this.coll.aggregate(list);
```

`$Match` stage works, but `$project` does not.

I get an error: `"errmsg" : "invalid operator '$contribs'" , "code" : 15999`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a `DBObject` when you were meant to create a `List`. Also `DBList` has been deprecated for a while now. Get used to using standard list notations:

```java
    List<DBObject> pipeline = Arrays.<DBObject>asList(
        new BasicDBObject(
            "$match",
            new BasicDBObject(
                "contribs.0", new BasicDBObject("$exists",true)
            )
        ),
        new BasicDBObject(
            "$project",
            new BasicDBObject(
                "contribs", new BasicDBObject("$arrayElemAt", Arrays.asList("$contribs",0))
            )
        )
    );

    AggregationOutput output = this.coll.aggrgate(pipeline);
```

Also note that in modern drivers you really should be using `Document` in place of all `DBObject` types.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was stuck for two hours. I know in Java Driver 3.0 there are new features, but I started my project with 2.14.1. Then I'm going to pass to Java Driver 3.0+.